# react core-ui with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, core-ui

I want to use react core-ui but there is no such thing as a core-ui react typescript project what should I do.

is there a way that I add typescript to the core-ui project?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://coreui.io/react/docs/templates/contents/), you need to buy the PRO version to download the Typescript boilerplate project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the core-ui website, the project has TypeScript support?
https://coreui.io/react/ui-components/

So I guess you shouldn't do anything...

Comment: so I create my components and pages in .tsx files and write typescript???